# BPEL schema result

Tags: xml, bpel

Its my XML result

```
   <message>
                      <parameters>
                      <ns2:getServiceDiscountListByIdResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                          <return>
                              <currDateE>2015-03-15T16:03:41.773+09:00</currDateE>
                              <currDateS>2015-03-30T16:03:49.285+09:00</currDateS>
                              <disc_cond_id>1</disc_cond_id>
                              <disc_condition>Хөгшин хүнд</disc_condition>
                              <disc_end_date>2015-03-30T16:03:49.285+09:00</disc_end_date>
                              <disc_name>Олон нийтийн хядрал</disc_name>
                              <disc_service_id>2</disc_service_id>
                              <disc_start_date>2015-03-15T16:03:41.773+09:00</disc_start_date>
                              <disc_type_id>2</disc_type_id>
                              <discount_value>4000</discount_value>
                              <org_id>1</org_id>
                              <serv_disc_id>3</serv_disc_id>
                              <service_id>109</service_id>
                              <tm_id>109</tm_id>
                              <tm_name>Шилбэ ясны эгц, хажуу зураг</tm_name>
                              <tm_pid>79</tm_pid>
                              <tm_type>2</tm_type>
                              <values_type>2</values_type>
                          </return>
                          <return>
                              <currDateE>2015-03-20T09:00:42.325+09:00</currDateE>
                              <currDateS>2015-05-22T09:00:45.606+09:00</currDateS>
                              <disc_cond_id>1</disc_cond_id>
                              <disc_condition>Хөгшин хүнд</disc_condition>
                              <disc_end_date>2015-05-22T09:00:45.606+09:00</disc_end_date>
                              <disc_name>хямдрал 2</disc_name>
                              <disc_service_id>3</disc_service_id>
                              <disc_start_date>2015-03-20T09:00:42.325+09:00</disc_start_date>
                              <discount_value>10000</discount_value>
                              <serv_disc_id>2</serv_disc_id>
                              <service_id>109</service_id>
                              <tm_id>109</tm_id>
                              <tm_name>Шилбэ ясны эгц, хажуу зураг</tm_name>
                              <tm_pid>79</tm_pid>
                              <tm_type>2</tm_type>
                              <values_type>2</values_type>
                          </return>
                          <return>
                              <currDateE>2015-03-16T14:45:17.019+09:00</currDateE>
                              <currDateS>2015-05-16T14:45:19.676+09:00</currDateS>
                              <disc_cond_id>1</disc_cond_id>
                              <disc_condition>Хөгшин хүнд</disc_condition>
                              <disc_end_date>2015-05-16T14:45:19.676+09:00</disc_end_date>
                              <disc_name>Хямдрал 1</disc_name>
                              <disc_service_id>1</disc_service_id>
                              <disc_start_date>2015-03-16T14:45:17.019+09:00</disc_start_date>
                              <disc_type_id>2</disc_type_id>
                              <discount_value>1000</discount_value>
                              <org_id>1</org_id>
                              <serv_disc_id>1</serv_disc_id>
                              <service_id>109</service_id>
                              <tm_id>109</tm_id>
                              <tm_name>Шилбэ ясны эгц, хажуу зураг</tm_name>
                              <tm_pid>79</tm_pid>
                              <tm_type>2</tm_type>
                              <values_type>2</values_type>
                          </return>
                      </ns2:getServiceDiscountListByIdResponse>
                      </parameters>
                  </message>
```

but soap result shows me

```
soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DiscountBpelResponse xmlns="http://service.org" xmlns:tns="http://service.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <tns:argument>
            <currDateE xmlns="">2015-03-15T16:03:41.773+09:00</currDateE>
            <currDateS xmlns="">2015-03-30T16:03:49.285+09:00</currDateS>
            <disc_cond_id xmlns="">1</disc_cond_id>
            <disc_condition xmlns="">Хөгшин хүнд</disc_condition>
            <disc_end_date xmlns="">2015-03-30T16:03:49.285+09:00</disc_end_date>
            <disc_name xmlns="">Олон нийтийн хядрал</disc_name>
            <disc_service_id xmlns="">2</disc_service_id>
            <disc_start_date xmlns="">2015-03-15T16:03:41.773+09:00</disc_start_date>
            <disc_type_id xmlns="">2</disc_type_id>
            <discount_value xmlns="">4000</discount_value>
            <org_id xmlns="">1</org_id>
            <serv_disc_id xmlns="">3</serv_disc_id>
            <service_id xmlns="">109</service_id>
            <tm_id xmlns="">109</tm_id>
            <tm_name xmlns="">Шилбэ ясны эгц, хажуу зураг</tm_name>
            <tm_pid xmlns="">79</tm_pid>
            <tm_type xmlns="">2</tm_type>
            <values_type xmlns="">2</values_type>
         </tns:argument>
      </DiscountBpelResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

how can i get all xml result . I using BPEL and java Service WSDL . And java client takes first one .Can someone help me :D im new BPEL user . Sorry for bad language